# Convert Unicode/UTF-8 string to lower/upper case using pure & pythonic library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, case-conversion

I use Google App Engine and cannot use any C/C++ extension, just pure & pythonic library to do conversion of Unicode/UTF-8 strings to lower/upper case. str.lower() and string.lowercase() don't.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`str` encoded in UTF-8 and `unicode` are two different types. Don't use `string`, use the appropriate method on the unicode object:

```
>>> print u'ĉ'.upper()
Ĉ
```

Decode `str` to `unicode` before using:

```
>>> print 'ĉ'.decode('utf-8').upper()
Ĉ
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this applicable to Vietnamese?

Comment: It should be. It's not hard to test in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: My code does not work for Russian and Vietnamese. I don't know other languages
http://oladic.appspot.com/add/ОИЧУНКАЛС
http://oladic.appspot.com/add/TÌNH%20YÊU
http://oladic.appspot.com/add/ĉĉĉĉ

Comment: Finally it worked! Thank you very much! I wish I could vote more!

Comment: Viet: you probably want to URL-encode unicode characters if you're putting them in a URL (although it's probably easier to just POST them as utf-8, assuming you're using a form to submit them).

Comment: Python 3: *'str' object has no attribute 'decode'*